# Symfony2: Add data attribute to select options

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm currently working on a Symfony2 project. I've set up a form with a select field and some options loaded from the database. Now I want to add a data attribute to every option of this select field which is needed by a JavaScript.

I know how to make "static" changes to the form layout, however I need a different attribute for every option now - what changes do I have to make in my twig template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution that fitted my needs here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3836#issuecomment-23145270

Answer (score 0):

The template is not the best place to do this.  Instead, modify the form before presenting it.  See [How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html).  Lots more flexibility there.